# Postgresql behavior at end of sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence

As per subject when a sequence hits its max val what happens?

What is the behavior? I have a big table with a sequence as a primary key and would like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: So, some stuff to clear up: a sequence is not a PK, it just feeds autogenerated values for newly inserted rows which don't specify an explicit value for it.  Also, you don't tell if the sequence is set to `CYCLE` or `NOCYCLE` (if you defined the PK with `serial`, the latter is the case).  If it is cycling, it will just restart at the `MINVALUE` defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you [try it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1bbe5/1), you'll get:

```
ERROR: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "testseq" (9223372036854775807): select nextval('testseq')
```

This is the case when the sequence is created automatically for a `serial` or `bigserial` column.  You can create a sequence with specifying `CYCLE`, in which case it will restart from the `MINVALUE` specified (or left at the default 1).